# The earliest recorded use of a UAV for military use was in July 1849, but if we include non-military UAVs, was there anything earlier?

Tags: history

The [history of drones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_unmanned_aerial_vehicles#Early_development) Wikipedia article starts with the Austrian incendiary balloons of July 1849 as the first recorded use of UAVs for the military.

Was this the earliest record of ***any*** UAV, whether for military use or not?

Answer (score 1):

I have recently written a dissertation on non-military drones and the first mention that I could find for what we would consider modern drones used in a context other than direct military action was when, in 1994, they were used as overhead surveillance for NATO envoys in Bosnia.

In terms of any UAV, not necessarily guided aircraft, the incendiary balloons are the earliest example I can think of, however, carrier pigeons were used as early as 1150 according to Wikipedia, so this may qualify.

Comment: Nice. However would the balloons of July 1849 be considered a "modern drone"? For this reason the article talks about UAVs in general rather than just drones!

Comment: @user1271772 my research was limited to drones that can be controlled via radio link, so by these standards an incendiary balloon would not qualify. Excellent question, though, the history of unmanned flight is certainly an interesting one!

Comment: @user1271772 I think I misunderstood your original question to mean only unmanned, yet manually controlled aircraft. I have amended my original answer.

Comment: I don't see any amendment to the answer (yet) !

Comment: @user1271772 has it come through now?

Comment: Yes! There was a lag

Comment: @user1271772 ah okay!

Comment: Carrier pigeons are, animals right? Can they be considered drones?

Comment: @user1271772 I’m not certain, but I guess you could consider it some form of onboard guidance? It really depends how you want to classify it. I did think it was a bit dubious but it’s the earliest use of anything airborne I can think of.